# How to add HTML tags with attribute containing hyphen in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to add script tags in my react app. 
I don't know how to handle attributes containing hyphens.

Following code is in the 'ComponentDidMount()'

```
const script2 = document.createElement("script");
script2.src ="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js";
script2.type = "text/javascript";
script2.id = "dropboxjs"
script2.data-app-key = "app key" // Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression
script2["data-app-key"] = "app key" // Also doesn't work

document.body.appendChild(script2)
```

Answer (score 8):

you should use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), the name of the custom attribute should be in `camelCase`

`script2.dataset.appKey = 'app key'`